# Why is my datepicker icon larger than the input field?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing a datepicker for my app and struggling to add an icon to the input field as the icon appears much larger than the input field.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMGWY.png

```
<div class="row">
   <legend class="form-group col-form-label col-sm-2"> 
     {{'dropdowns.effective_date' | translate}}</legend>
       <div class="input-group col-sm-10">
          <div class="input-group-append">
             <span class="input-group-text" (click)="dpr1.show()">
               <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-label="Date"></i>
             </span>
       </div>
      <input type="text"class="form-control placeholder" 
[(ngModel)]="searchModel.readingEffectiveDate"#dpr1="bsDatepicker" 
bsDatepicker placeholder="{{'placeholder.startDate' | 
translate}}"name="searchModel.readingEffectiveDate" 
[bsConfig]="datePickerOptions" > 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Hoobs, would you be able to add your CSS that relates to the above code to your question please?

Comment: `Help us to help you` Provide rendered HTML and CSS